# Reading lists from a low level in app.config file

Tags: c#, xml, config

I want to read a list of values from the app.config xml file. Here is an example app.config file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2" />
    </startup>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="test" value="testoutput" />
  </appSettings>      
  <references>
    <firstLevel>
      <ref name="first1"></ref>
      <ref name="first2"></ref>
      <ref name="first3"></ref>
    </firstLevel>
    <secondLevel>
      <ref name="second"></ref>
    </secondLevel>
    <thirdLevel>
      <ref name="third"></ref>
    </thirdLevel>    
  </references>
</configuration>
```

I can get the app settings part. I would like to get the 'ref' tags and put them in a list. For example, configuration/references/firstlevel. I would like to loop through all of its children and put each name into a list.

So the list would be `["first1", "first2", "first3"]`

Answer (score 0):

All required documentation how to create custom configuration sections is listed
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx